# Need to monitor sudo permission

Tags: sudo, notifications

I'm just learning Linux for educational purposes, but, I am really enjoying this operation system.

For a homework I have to implement a system that contains something that the users can see as the safest when managing a server, so, I'd want to configure something like:

If a user with root permission needs to install a software or a lib, when typing `sudo xxxx` command the manager of a team (Information security regularly) must receive a notification that user `john` is installing the software `xxxx`.

Does someone knows if this is possible?

For now my lab is running in Ubuntu

Comment: The usual log file will be `/var/log/sudo` - this could be periodically processed "in some way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a modern distribution with a non-exotic configuration this is already happening, see the output of `journalctl -xe`

You can parse it with something like the command below to get something easier to read:

```
journalctl -e | perl -ne 'print "\"$1\" ran \"$2\" with sudo\n"  if(/.*sudo.*?\:\s*(\S+).*COMMAND=(.*)/);'
```

Comment: Could I copy the output of this comand in a .txt file automatically? this is because I'd like to send it also automatically to an external repository with a cron job...

Thanks in advance

Comment: add `>> somefilewheretheoutputshouldgo` at the end

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
I just marked your post as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

`sudo` logs authentication events by default; you can see these with `journalctl` on systemd-based systems. This can be configured to send the logs to a remote system where they can be analysed.

`sudo` also supports its own remote logging protocol, described in [`man sudo_logsrv.proto`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.8/sudo_logsrv.proto.man.html). This requires a server process supporting that protocol; `sudo` provides one in [`sudo_logsrvd`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.8/sudo_logsrvd.man.html), but you could write a more specific implementation matching your exact notification requirements. Once a server is available, you can instruct `sudo` to send information to it by adding it to `log_servers` in [`sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.8/sudoers.man.html).

In both cases, `sudo` can log much more than authentication events; it can even log complete user sessions.